# How could these trolls survive on this diet?

Tags: creature-design, food

I'm working with trolls who are beings made of stone. Troll species/races can range in size from small (3-4ft) to gigantic (hundreds of feet tall--big enough that they're no longer mobile and must be fed by others), but are typically in the 7 - 14ft range.

For all species/races the troll diet consists primarily of meat and metal, but they'll also eat fibers and plastics.

I can see the metal providing minerals/nutrients they need to support their bodily functions, but I'm lost on how meat would be a benefit to them; same thing with fibers and plastic.

How could they support themselves on this diet? If they couldn't, what would a more realistic one look like?

Comment: They also eat cats. Don't forget that bit.

Comment: @key_abrade and cats apparently taste like candy! I decided to leave that bit off because Meat A merely tasting good while Meat B is so addictive that they'll actively pursue it at any given opportunity seemed like it would complicate matters.

Comment: (I know the realistic answer to this question is "the creators did not put that much thought into it," but *I* have)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about an existing work of fiction, not building a fictional world. Such questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: @sphennings where would a more appropriate place to ask it be? Though I'm happy with the answer I got from Daron

Comment: @Writinglittledetails Sci-Fi/Fantasy might answer such questions but I'd make sure to it's a fit before posting more questions. Beyond that I don't know. There are plenty of questions that just don't have a place anywhere on the SO network.

Comment: @sphennings Gotcha. In this case I'm writing stories within the series' universe and am trying to do a deeper dive into/add realism into concepts that the show doesn't address, so I thought World Building would be a good place to ask it.  I'll try and frame my questions more generally with the "nothing based on existing universes" rules in mind.

Comment: @Writinglittledetails If the core of your question is on topic for WB you can always file off the labels and ask that question. "Could a forest moon exist?" is much more on topic than "Could the forest moon of Endor exist?".

Comment: @sphennings Done!

Comment: How will your troll *gather* this diet in the first place, especially meat ? Meat requires hunting. I wonder if this creature can hunt, being heavy, slow, or even immobile ? I don't see a 7-15ft stone giant catch a cat for dinner...

Comment: @Goodies I was thinking of trolls like elephants: they're huge and lumbering, but can move fast when necessary and cover more ground due to their size. Re: hunting, cats would be an opportunistic treat if the cat was close enough to grab. Most animals they'd just scent out, then chase down and grab (probably over a period of time, persistence style)

Comment: @Writinglittledetails elephants are herbivores, they will never be able to hunt. These stone trolls would be 3-4x as heavy as elephants, same size. There is no "grab" or any form of agile movement, the prey will escape easily. And there would be enormous energy demands, requiring the troll to graze stone, fibers or plastics all day. These foods are not energy-rich foods. In short: I do not think your creature would be viable (at all). Your troll is too heavy to feed itself. Let alone on the diet you propose.

Comment: @goodies would the stone exoskeleton/fleshy innard solution proposed by make a difference? In that case the stone would be more like a thick hide (maybe 1.5-2in) while the rest of the troll is more normal tissue. Also, the thickness of the hide wouldn't be uniform in this case; it would be much thinner where flexibility is required, such as around joints.

Comment: @Writinglittledetails when they have bone and flesh internally, they'll need even more organic food. An animal requiring meat is a predator. Why - and how - would a *predator* develop a heavy, stone exoskeleton ? Drop the meat requirement, it does not fit in. You could make them herbivore, or omnivore.. like eating worms or insects as supplementary. The main part of the diet is bulk food. These trolls are big, they will need a lot of food, why limit them too much.

Comment: @Goodies Perhaps it is a cold blooded ambush predator that waits perfectly still for months on end, until the wildlife grows accustomed to its presence as just another rock formation. Then one day a pigeon lands on it or a dog cocks a leg and the troll suddenly grabs and devours the animal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stone Exoskeleton. Fleshy Innards.**

The trolls have hard stone on the outside and normal fleshy stuff on the inside.

They need to consume stone and metal to maintain their exoskeleton, and a  mundane diet of meat and plants to maintain their blood and guts and organs.

Their senses are rather dull and sometimes they eat clothes which they mistake to be made of edible plant (cotton, bamboo) or animal (wool, sweat) material. Similar to how goats will eat almost anything including gnawing on wooden fence posts.

Comment: Now that you say that, that makes perfect sense. Offhand I don't recall the show giving us any examples of their internal anatomy, but being a mix of stone/flesh would explain why they need a diet of mixed organic/inorganic foodstuffs.

Comment: Re: the fibers/plastics bit, the trolls in the show are sapient and *generally* intelligent, so they know those things aren't plants or animals. They just...like them for some reason. Perhaps they're the equivalent of candy for humans, in that they provide no nutritional value but they just enjoy eating them.

Comment: @Writinglittledetails Perhaps their "taste buds" respond more to texture than to taste. Hence they enjoy chewing on inedible fibres just as much as chewing on edible fibres.

Comment: Ooooh, I like that. I feel like texture is easy to forget as a component of food in fantasy even though it's an important part of how humans judge a food's desirability. I can see trolls being discerning in that way, based on how they're presented in the series

Comment: @Writinglittledetails Can you click the upvote arrow please?

Comment: I tried; I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. It says my feedback has been recorded, but clearly that's not useful since it doesn't reflect on the UI side.

Comment: I see it is acknowledged, I'll put a +1, this answer covers my remarks in the opening, I agree it should be omnivore, eat anything, or anything except meat.

Answer (score 3):

## Chemistry and good design

Being a troll is like being in love.  No one can *tell* you you're a troll; you just *are*.

Trolls, being the supreme form of life in the Cosmos, reorganize any and all matter in the most beneficial way.  This reorganization has been misleadingly envisioned as "[gray goo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_goo)", but there are some major errors in that description.  After all, trolls can be hard rather than gooey - it's just a matter of organization.  If some censorious people seek to strike them, that may momentarily be polymerized to match the hardness and texture of stone where they are struck - otherwise, not so much.  Also, trolls aren't gray.  Also, obviously, an organism made of highly advanced nanotechnology meant to take over the world is not a passive "goo" but the leading intellect of the universe.  Above all, naturally, the domination of the Earth by trolls should be welcomed as the next stage of evolution rather than disparaged as a 'catastrophe'.

The lesser minds of the world will clutch their dirty socks close to their chests as they seek relief in their so carefully moderated forums, but the writing is on the wall.  And rest assured a troll sprayed it there!

Comment: This idea actually works better than the trolls being made of real stone when it comes to how they reproduce-- the current planned method is that each parent places a bit of their stone into an egg, and over the course of years the separate pieces somehow combine/grow to form their child. I don't *love* that idea, though, because it relies too much on handwavey magic for my tastes. The stone being something that can replicate/grow would lend that process the realism I'm looking for.

Comment: @Writinglittledetails An organism consisting of bits if different individuals is known as a chimaera, and it's a real thing, mostly seen in twins that fuse. So eggs made of multiple additions is actually not that bad, biologically.

Comment: @dwkraus hmmm. Now that you say that, I could see there being something about the egg that triggers each parent's tissue to try and grow a new organism, and their proximity causes them to fuse in the way you describe. Look at that. Two questions solved for the price of one!

Comment: @Writinglittledetails - I don't know the series, but on the Old Internet we learned that all trolls are actually male.  Trolls can impregnate virtually anything - tree stumps, farm animals, online messaging services - with what is essentially just little bits of troll.  Given a fertile environment (and what isn't?) they grow.  When the tiny trolls meet, they fuse together.  If a large troll is mistreated, it can break into chunks of rock that put out arms and legs and spread out over the countryside.

Answer (score 2):

**Anything that burns is food.**

The trolls contain a furnace that powers them.  A full troll will be hot from its internal fire.  They can feed on anything that will burn.  That means meat, fat, bone, plastic, fiber, wood, coal and even metal which they can oxidize (aluminum is especially good).

They need to eat stone because they are made of it, but it does not provide any energy.

Comment: I like this answer too! One of the mountain-sized trolls has boiling lava for digestive acid. I was going to handwave away that as a difference between species, but if *all* trolls have furnaces for innards and the big ones just have it at a larger scale, that keeps a biological baseline between all trolls.